# Change SQL Service Account

Tags: sql-server, sql

I just have the sa user to log into a sql 2005 express server. the service is running as networkservice. is there a way to change it to localsystem with sql server management studio or any other software connecting from the network. i have no other login to the server

Comment: Why do you need to change the account running the service? Are you trying to solve a larger problem?

Comment: see my comment in answer 1

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately (or perhaps *fortunately*), no, you cannot.

You could in theory gain access to the computer via the xp_cmdshell SP, which you have permission to run when you use a SQL login that has the sysadmin server role.

However, the NetworkService account does not have access to alter service configuration (including services it is running itself).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190693(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: thanks i know xp_cmdshell. nobody knows the machine admin password. so i would like to use xp_cmdshell to create an admin account but the networkservice has insuffitient rights to do this. so i thought maybe there is a way to change the service account using sql management studio or another sql management software to localsystem. then i would have rights to do this.

Comment: Do you have absolute control over the server? There are ways to reset the administrator account password but they are hackey. Is the server on a domain? You should be able to connect using services.msc to that server or you could connect with the Computer Management mmc to alter the Remote Desktop Users group or Admins to include an account you know as long as you or someone else have a Domain Admin account to use. You've probably already tried those but I figured I'd mention it in case.

Comment: thnaks. i know all this options of managing a remote system. my problem is that the server isn't in a domain and i don't have an windows account. i just have the sa for sql. so if there is no way to change it with sql management then i just can overwrite the admin password with locally boot erd commander. i'm not happy about this, because the server isn't next to me.